# MySQLi dynamically created prepared statement fails: "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a piece of code that reads a crash log and other metadata from a MySQL database before sending it back to the requester as JSON (this code is called by an AJAX function on another page). Optionally, filters can be specified with GET, which alter the prepared statement to filter for only the specified results - for example, to only show results from one app version. Here is the code in question:

```
$conn = new mysqli($sql_servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, "Crashes");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //failed
    die();
}

$sql="
SELECT ID,phone,appver,osver,user_agent,username,message,app_name,date_received FROM Crashes WHERE ";
$params="";
$params2="";
if (isset($_GET["filter_phone"])) {
    $sql .= "phone = ? AND "; //i.e "WHERE phone = ? AND (...osver = ? AND appver = ? etc)"
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_phone"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_appver"])) {
    $sql .= "appver = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_appver"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_osver"])) {
    $sql .= "osver = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_osver"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_user_agent"])) {
    $sql .= "user_agent = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_user_agent"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_username"])) {
    $sql .= "username = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_username"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_message"])) {
    $sql .= "message = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_message"]';
}
if (isset($_GET["filter_app_name"])) {
    $sql .= "app_name = ? AND ";
    $params.="s";
    $params2.=', $_GET["filter_app_name"]';
}
$sql.="1";

//echo "\$params: ".$params."<br>";
//echo "\$params2: ".$params2."<br>";
//echo "<br>\$stmt->bind_param(\$params$params2);<br>";
//echo var_dump($_GET);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
exec("\$stmt->bind_param(\$params$params2);");

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    //echo "<br>Success!";
} else {
    //echo "<br>Failure: ".$stmt->error;
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$out = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($out, $row);
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

This code works perfectly when no filters are specified - however, when any filter is specified, the statement fails with the error `No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement`. I have verified that the code in the `exec()` *should* be (for example, if the user_agent filter is set) `$stmt->bind_param($params, $_GET["filter_user_agent"]);`

Additionally, the SQL query works perfectly when I use the query but just manually replace the `?`s with the filters, so it does not appear to be a problem with the initial query, but rather the prepared statement. Help would be much appreciated.

NB: The commented out `echo`s are for debug purposes, and are usually disabled, but I have left them in to show how I got the information that I currently have.

EDIT: Answered my own question below - the error was that I was using `exec()` - a function which **exec**utes external shell commands, whereas what I wanted was `eval()`, which **eval**uates a string input and the executes it as a PHP script.

Comment: Try exec("\$stmt->bind_param(\$params\$params2);"); I assume you somehow execute the code and escape the variables - following that logic you should escape both params and params2, perhaps? Edit: I moved this to answer in case it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was simply mistaken as to the function of `exec()`. (Too much Python?) `exec()` runs an ***external shell command***, whereas what I was looking for was `eval()` which evaluates and runs any string inputted as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you never actually use the values `$params` and `$params2`. You concatenate them, but where is your `$stmt->bind_param()`? It's commented out?

I don't see a `$conn->prepare("")` either. Did you omit some code?

`$conn` is defined as a mysqli object and then again never used. Something's not right here.

Edit:

Try exec("\$stmt->bind_param(\$params\$params2);"); I assume you somehow execute the code and escape the variables - following that logic you should escape both params and params2, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I managed to omit the most important part of the code somehow. I'd edited it back in now though. Side-note: this would probably have been better as a comment.

Comment: exec("\$stmt->bind_param(\$params$params2);"); What the hell is this?

Comment: I put it as an answer because the reason your script doesn't work would be because of the lack of binding method and lack of use of the mysqli object. Hard to give you a better answer then :)

Comment: In double quotes, unescaped variables will evaluate from inside the string. For example, `$foo='bar'; echo "super $foo"` will return "super bar". This doesn't happen in single quotes. It's simply a more compact way of doing it, rather than the fairly ugly `"foo".$bar."baz"`.

Comment: Reply to the edit: The reason for the `exec` is that `$params2` is a variable that looks like `, $_GET["filter_phone"], $_GET["filter_appver"]`, and it is unescaped in the `exec` so that the final code going into the `exec` looks like this: `$stmt->bind_param($params, $_GET["filter_user_agent"]);`. The `exec` is necessary for adding the extra arguments to `$stmt->bind_param()`.

Comment: If that doesn't help then I don't know, sorry.